# Is there a difference between BigDecimal("0") and BigDecimal.ZERO?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, zero

Either for comparisons or initialization of a new variable, does it make a difference which one of these you use?

I know that BigDecimal.ZERO is a 1.5 feature, so that's a concern, but assuming I'm using 1.5 does it matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`BigDecimal.ZERO` is a predefined constant and therefore doesn't have to be evaluated from a string at runtime as `BigDecimal("0")` would be. It will be faster and won't require creation of a new object.

If your code needs to run on pre-1.5, then you can use the (much maligned) Singleton pattern to create an object equivalent to `BigDecimal.ZERO`. The first time it is used, it would call `BigDecimal("0")` to create a zero object, and return that object on subsequent calls. Otherwise, if your code is running on a 1.5 system, your singleton object can just return `BigDecimal.ZERO` with no runtime penalty.

Comment: new BigDecimal("0") creates a new object instance every time but BigDecimal.ZERO does not create new instances.

Comment: There is no need to create a singleton if you just create public static final in a final class called along the lines of "Constants", and just use that.

Comment: @Spencer that's the same thing

Answer (score 14):

Using ZERO doesn't create a new object or require any parsing. Definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Before talking about runtime penalties, make sure that this piece of code matters. Set up profiling and measure the complete use case.

Nevertheless, prefer `Bigdecimal.ZERO` as it's checked at compile time whereas you can accidentally type `new BigDecimal("9")`, which the compiler will accept, but which will cause bugs into your application.

Comment: You could say this about any number.

Comment: @RobertL: Yes, but this eliminates this for one of the numbers, reducing said risk by 1/10 :). It also has no chance of throwing a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 3):

Out of curiosity I checked to constructor for BigDecimal and it doesn't have any optimizations for the "0" string.  So definitely yes, there's a difference.

Comment: There'd be a difference anyway, as calling new BigDecimal("0") will create a new object each time.

Comment: Can't argue that. I was just curious to know how large a penalty not using ZERO would be.  Turns out it's substantial since the constructor for BigDecimal is pretty heavy.