# Converting whole program from Int to BigInteger

Tags: java, int, biginteger, type-conversion

So I already have this whole entire class done in Int and now I had to convert it to BigInteger. Main objective is so I can store the coefficients as the BigIntegers  for large coefficients. I am getting a null pointer error with the code but I knew that BigInteger was immutable and needed that format. Just maybe another eye or maybe I'm just not doing this correctly.

```
public class Polynomial {

private BigInteger[] coef;  // coefficients

private int deg;     // degree of polynomial (0 for the zero polynomial)



    /** Creates the constant polynomial P(x) = 1.
      */
    public Polynomial(){
        coef = new BigInteger[1];
        coef[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        deg = 0;
    }



    /** Creates the linear polynomial of the form P(x) =  x + a.
      */
    public Polynomial(int a){
        coef = new BigInteger[2];
        coef[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        coef[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
        deg = 1;
    }




    /** Creates the polynomial P(x) = a * x^b.
      */
    public Polynomial(int a, int b) { 
        coef = new BigInteger[b+1];
        coef[b] = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
        deg = degree();
    }
    public Polynomial(BigInteger a, int b) { 
        coef = new BigInteger[b+1];
        coef[b] = a;
        deg = degree();
    }






    /** Return the degree of this polynomial (0 for the constant polynomial).
      */
    public int degree() {
        int d = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coef.length; i++)
            if (coef[i] != BigInteger.valueOf(0)) d = i;
        return d;
    }





    /** Return the sum of this polynomial and b, i.e., return c = this + b.
      */
    public Polynomial plus(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.deg, b.deg));
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(a.coef[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= b.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(b.coef[i]);

        c.deg = c.degree();
        return c;
    }






    /** Return the difference of this polynomial and b, i.e., return (this - b).
      */
    public Polynomial minus(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.deg, b.deg));
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(a.coef[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= b.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].subtract(b.coef[i]);

        c.deg = c.degree();
        return c;
    }






    /** Return the product of this polynomial and b, i.e., return (this * b).
      */
    public Polynomial times(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, a.deg + b.deg);
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= b.deg; j++)
                c.coef[i+j] = c.coef[i+j].add(a.coef[i].multiply(b.coef[j]));
        c.deg = c.degree();
        return c;
    }






    /** Return the composite of this polynomial and b, i.e., return this(b(x))  - compute using Horner's method.
      */
    public Polynomial compose(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, 0);
        for (int i = a.deg; i >= 0; i--) {
            Polynomial term = new Polynomial(a.coef[i], 0);
            c = term.plus(b.times(c));
        }
        return c;
    }




    /** Return true whenever this polynomial and b are identical to one another.
      */
    public boolean equals(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        if (a.deg != b.deg) return false;
        for (int i = a.deg; i >= 0; i--)
            if (a.coef[i] != b.coef[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }





    /** Evaluate this polynomial at x, i.e., return this(x).
      */
    public int evaluate(int x) {
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = deg; i >= 0; i--){
            coef[i] = coef[i].add(BigInteger.valueOf(x * p));
        p = coef[i].intValue();
    }
        return p;
    }






    /** Return the derivative of this polynomial.
      */
    public Polynomial differentiate() {
        if (deg == 0) return new Polynomial(0, 0);
        Polynomial deriv = new Polynomial(0, deg - 1);
        deriv.deg = deg - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++)
            deriv.coef[i] = coef[i + 1].multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i+1));        
    return deriv;
    }





    /** Return a textual representationof this polynomial.
      */
    public String toString() {
        if (deg ==  0) return "" + coef[0];
        if (deg ==  1) return String.valueOf(coef[1]) + "x + " + String.valueOf(coef[0]);
        String s = String.valueOf(coef[deg]) + "x^" + deg;
        for (int i = deg-1; i > 0; i--) {
            if      (coef[i].intValue() == 0) continue;
            else if (coef[i].intValue()  > 0) s = s + " + " + ( coef[i].intValue());
            else if (coef[i].intValue()  < 0) s = s + " - " + (-coef[i].intValue());
            if      (i == 1) s = s + "x";
            else if (i >  1) s = s + "x^" + i;
        }
        return s;
    }






    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial zero = new Polynomial(1, 0);

        Polynomial p1   = new Polynomial(4, 3);
        Polynomial p2   = new Polynomial(3, 2);
        Polynomial p3   = new Polynomial(-1, 0);
        Polynomial p4   = new Polynomial(-2, 1);
        Polynomial p    = p1.plus(p2).plus(p3).plus(p4);   // 4x^3 + 3x^2  - 2x - 1

        Polynomial q1   = new Polynomial(3, 2);
        Polynomial q2   = new Polynomial(5, 0);
        Polynomial q    = q1.minus(q2);                     // 3x^2 - 5


        Polynomial r    = p.plus(q);
        Polynomial s    = p.times(q);
        Polynomial t    = p.compose(q);

        System.out.println("zero(x) =     " + zero);
        System.out.println("p(x) =        " + p);
        System.out.println("q(x) =        " + q);
        System.out.println("p(x) + q(x) = " + r);
        System.out.println("p(x) * q(x) = " + s);
        System.out.println("p(q(x))     = " + t);
        System.out.println("0 - p(x)    = " + zero.minus(p));
        System.out.println("p(3)        = " + p.evaluate(3));
        System.out.println("p'(x)       = " + p.differentiate());
        System.out.println("p''(x)      = " + p.differentiate().differentiate());


        Polynomial poly = new Polynomial();

        for(int k=0; k<=4; k++){
            poly = poly.times(new Polynomial(-k));
        }

        System.out.println(poly);
   }

}
```

Comment: On which line is your null pointer exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Polynomial.plus(polynomial.java:67)
 at Polynomial.main(polynomial.java:201)

Comment: I'm assuming if it is wrong there then it is also wrong in the other mutator classes.

Comment: Yeah, very good.  Which line is line 67?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(a.coef[i]);

Comment: thats in the plus mutator

Comment: Probably unrelated but there's no way your `equals` method is going to work, since you're using `!=` to compare objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you initialize your array of `BigInteger`, the values are `null` because you have specified an array of objects (if it was `int[]` then initial values are 0).

As you can see from your constructor:

```
public Polynomial(int a, int b) { 
     coef = new BigInteger[b+1];
     coef[b] = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
     deg = degree();
}
```

You have only assigned `coef[b]`, the other values remain `null`.

Hence in first iteration of loop in method `plus(Polynomial b)`, `c.coef[0]` is null hence `NullPointerException` when your loop tries to call `c.coef[0].add(a.coef[0])`.

Suggestion: define a method to initialize all the `BigInteger` values in an array to 0 to be consistent with declaration of `int[]` and call in your constructors. Example:

```
private static void initializeBigIntegerArray(BigInteger[] bigIntegers) {
   for (int i=0; i<bigIntegers.length; i++) {
      // So you don't overwrite anything you assign explicitly
      if (bigInteger[i] == null) {
         bigIntegers[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: how would I compare it to null though? I don't think that would work

Comment: @JohnV you can check a value is `null`. Try it and see for yourself. The reason you get the `NullPointerException` in your code is because you're trying to call a method from a object that is `null` i.e. object has not been instantiated. In the `initalizeBigIntegerArray` method I am not doing that.

Comment: Thank you XLM and sorry for my stupidity. I, unlike you, have never had to deal with bigint before. You helped a lot! I appreciate that.

Comment: `BigInteger.ZERO` is also your friend here.

Comment: @JohnV no worries, I'm glad it helped but it's actually thanks to everyone here that participated including yourself. Also I haven't actually used `BigInteger` before and had to look up the Java doc (hence I didn't realise I could use `BigInteger.ZERO`). My point is that it isn't about memorizing arbitrary facts, it's about understanding and learning how or why something works the way it does. Lastly, don't call yourself stupid, we're all learning so keep at it.

Comment: @Affe +1 thanks for pointing this out! I've updated my answer as that should be the approach taken for reasons indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269669/is-there-a-difference-between-bigdecimal0-and-bigdecimal-zero).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in Java an array of objects is actually an array of *references* to objects.  So you need to create a BigInteger object for *every* array element.  The entries you don't assign are not 0, they are null.

Answer (score 1):

So in the `plus` method, you create this polynomial `c` whose backing array contains one zero, and several nulls.  Then you go ahead and try to operate on all the coefficients in that polynomial, including all those nulls.  So you're calling methods on variables for which an object hasn't been created yet, and that's what makes your null pointer problem.

When you create each polynomial, make sure you have a `BigInteger` created for every entry in the backing array.